# This Action Show DeadLock Erorr-1205

Tags: sql-server, database

```
ALTER PROCEDURE USP_USM_PERMISSION_ACCESS
    @XMLpermissons XML = NULL,
    @UserRole int = 0,
    @Actioncode varchar(2),
    @Msgout int = 0 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN
    IF (@Actioncode = 'G')
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        SELECT
            @UserRole AS Role,
            MenuNode.value('Menuid[1]', 'INT') AS Menuid,
            --MenuNode.value('PermitedActions[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
            value AS PermittedAction
        INTO
            #temptable
        FROM 
            @XMLpermissons.nodes('/ArrayOfMenuMaster/MenuMaster') AS XmlData(MenuNode)
        CROSS APPLY 
            STRING_SPLIT(LEFT(MenuNode.value('PermitedActions[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), LEN(MenuNode.value('PermitedActions[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) - 1), ',') s;

        DELETE b 
        FROM Usm_Permisons b
        LEFT JOIN #temptable a WITH(nolock) ON b.Menuid = a.Menuid 
                                            AND b.Roleid = a.Role 
                                            AND b.Permissionid = a.PermittedAction
        WHERE a.Menuid IS NULL

        INSERT INTO Usm_Permissions (Menuid, Roleid, PermittedAction)
            SELECT a.Menuid, a.Role, a.PermittedAction 
            FROM #temptable a WITH(nolock)
            LEFT JOIN Usm_Permissions b ON a.Menuid = b.Menuid 
                                        AND a.Role = b.Roleid 
                                        AND a.PermittedAction = b.Permissionid
            WHERE b.Menuid IS NULL

        DROP TABLE #temptable

        SET @Msgout = 1

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END
END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH                
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0                
        ROLLBACK                

    EXEC [dbo].[USP_GETERRORINFO]                  
END CATCH
```

I try to send some rows which are present in `Usm_Permissions` and not present in which I have sent that are be deleted and which row I sent but not present in `Usm_Permissions` then it will inserted.

Comment: "with(nolock)" - code smells

Comment: What's the point of `with (nolock)` on a local #temp table again?

Comment: Deadlocks require *two* transactions. The [deadlock graph](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-graphical-representation-sql-server-deadlock-graph/) will show you which queries/stored procedures resulted in a deadlock. `NOLOCK` can easily be the cause. It doesn't mean "don't take locks". It means "don't respect locks, read duplicate rows, miss others and throw errors". Check [NOLOCK Is Bad And You Probably Shouldn’t Use It.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/11/nolock-is-bad-and-you-probably-shouldnt-use-it/) Data modifying queries are the worst cases

Comment: To diagnose a deadlock we need at a minimum the following: the two queries involved (if they are part of a transaction then the whole transaction batch), the query plans for those (please share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan), the tables *and indexes* involved, and the XDL/XML deadlock graph. Without this we cannot give you a proper answer.